# MVC 3 - switch between databases (same schema) on runtime

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, sql-server-2008, entity-framework-4, ado.net, connection-string

I have 2 SQL Server 2008 R2 databases (SQLEXPRESS): database1 and database2

ConnectionString (ADO.net) should contain databaseName1 When User is User1

ConnectionString (ADO.net) should contain databaseName2 When User is User2

To manipulate data, I use the same EF model for both

Using compiled MVC 3 Application, I would like to switch between databases at runtime,

also for security reasons, I should avoid putting connection string in web.config

Please, if any advise, for how to do that

Many Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why can't you put the connecting string in web.config? It is more secure to have it there than in your source code unencrypted. Read here about how you encrypt your config: http://chiragrdarji.wordpress.com/2008/08/11/how-to-encrypt-connection-string-in-webconfig/

If you worry about that kind of security you might have other problems.

Comment: On the shared hosting server there will be no source code, the project should be compiled before hosted, web.config is reachable since it is hosted, I am looking for a way to compile the encryption key in the application

Comment: You should be able to use this: http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=185 so you encrypt the file when it starts up or something. Or you can setup a build step like this: http://litemedia.info/encrypt-your-web-config-with-msbuild.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check that, and what about database switching at runtime?

Comment: I would suggest creating your own connection string provider that you use to select connection string when you create your db connection. That is one solution.

Comment: `if(someValue) { connection = new Connection(connectionStringX); } else { connection = new Connection(connectionStringY); }`.